# Receiving Leap data from WebSocket server to Unity3D directly

Tags: node.js, websocket, leap-motion

I try to make connection between Leap Motion and mobile devices in Unity3D, via node.js.
Here are two examples I found online using node.js, [this](http://xseignard.github.io/2013/06/25/interfacing-leap-motion-with-arduino-thanks-to-nodejs/) and [this](http://marctan.com/blog/2013/05/26/leap-motion-and-android-a-match-made-in-heaven/).
Now, I have successfully receive data from Leap Motion in this procedure:

1. Receiving JSON-formatted messages from "localhost:6437" in node.js
2. Parsing and Writing received data on another port (I use "localhost:8000") in node.js
3. Reading stream from port: 8000 in Unity3D

However, I wonder if it's possible to receive data DIRECTLY from "localhost:6437"? then maybe node.js is not needed.
I have tried to write in C# using TcpClient, but when I check "NetworkStream.DataAvailable", it returns false.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For that you would need a WebSocket client, not a TCP client.